# jni can't find method from native lib?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

in Java ,the native method :

`public native String hello();`

```
package name:  pack

class name: Hello
```

C++:  method name:

```
jstring
Java_pack_Hello_hello
(
    JNIEnv* env,
    jobject this
)
```

I use ndk compile this file ,but app crash ;

after i add this line :  `extern "C"`  into my `hello.cpp` 
the error is gone ,every thing is ok.

so  why ?

Answer (score 1):

The format of method names used in JNI is different to regular C and C++
if you don't specify extern 'C'
JNI will be unable to find the function to match your Java native declarations.
alternatively you can try RegisterNatives()